# Python: retrieving the length of a list of lists

Tags: python, typeerror

When trying to retrieve the length of a list of lists I get the following error: **"TypeError: 'float' object is not callable"**

My code looks something like this:

```
list = []    
for line in text:
    regex = re.search("(.*) (.*) (.*)")
    a = float(regex.group(1))
    b = float(regex.group(2))
    c = float(regex.group(3))
    list.append([a, b, c])

newlist = []
for entry in list:
    if entry[0] < 10:
         newlist.append(entry)

if len(newlist) >1:
    do something
```

The list of lists ('newlist') is produced with no issues, e.g. **[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]]**

And it's definitely a list, i.e. **type 'list'**

But when I try to use:

```
len(list)
```

I just get the TypeError. I could've missed something really obvious but I just cannot see what I'm doing wrong, can anyone help?

Thank you :)

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name - it will shadow the builtin.

Comment: Please leave the questioner's code as it is. If `list` has been reused it's like likely other names (including `len`) have been shadowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with the list, but the `len`. You probably used the name `len` as one of your variable. That's why you can't call the function `len`, it's being shadowed.

`len`, `list`, `str`, and [others](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) are built in-functions. You should avoid naming variables with a same name.

Comment: You absolute genius, thank you so much, I feel like such an idiot! :D

Comment: To add @user3097536 whenever you run into a "TypeError <XYZ> object not callable" it's likely that you've shadowed something built in or an import with a local variable name.

Answer (score 0):

The program works fine for me, check your input format

Full program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

mylist = []
for line in ("0.1 0.2 0.3", "20 0.3 0.1", "0.2 0.1 5"):
    regex = re.search("(.*) (.*) (.*)", line)
    a = float(regex.group(1))
    b = float(regex.group(2))
    c = float(regex.group(3))
    mylist.append([a, b, c])

newlist = []
for entry in mylist:
    if entry[0] < 10:
         newlist.append(entry)

if len(newlist) > 1:
    print newlist

if len(mylist) > 1:
    print mylist
```